# how to bind data with series in asp.net stacked coulmn chart

Tags: asp.net, mschart

When i want to bind dynamic data with series , error occure that you cannot bind data with series ....how i do???

```
`enter code here`
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart4" runat="server">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" Label='<%# Eval("coulmname") %>'>
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: How are you doing it ? you need to show some code, the markup does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your chart to a DataTable:

```
chart1.DataSource = dataTable1;
chart1.DataBind();
```

Then in your markup specify your data members using YValueMembers and XValueMember properties:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chart1" runat="server">
  <Series>
    <asp:Series Name="series1" YValueMembers="coulmname1" XValueMember="coulmname2" IsValueShownAsLabel="true" ></asp:Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```